# How to display the actual number of each word being vectored

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, scikit-learn

I'm working through a tutorial book on Scikit-learn, and one of the sections has this block of code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ['The dog ate a sandwich, the wizard transfigured a sandwich, and I ate a sandwich']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
print vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()
```

And when I run it, I get this:

```
[[2 1 3 1 1]]
```

When I *should* be getting both of these:

```
[[2 1 3 1 1]]
{u'sandwich': 2, u'wizard': 4, u'dog': 1, u'transfigured': 3, u'ate': 0}
```

How can I change my code to get the actual words & number of each word being vectored, and not just the vectors themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would access the `.vocabulary_` property after the model is fitted:

```
>>> vectorizer.vocabulary_
{'ate': 0, 'dog': 1, 'sandwich': 2, 'transfigured': 3, 'wizard': 4}
```